# JavaScript Alternative To Possessive Quantifiers In Dynamic Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, reluctant-quantifiers

I'm using JavaScript to extract a subset of "siblings" from a comma-delimited string of members I call a "generation" string.

Metaphorically speaking, the members are all from the same generation, but they are not all siblings (from the same parents). Here's an example:

```
// This is the generation string to search
var generation  = 'ABAA,ABAB,ABAC,ABAD,ABBA,ACAA,ACAB,ACAD,AEAB,AEAD,AFAA';

// This is the member for whom to extract siblings (member included)
var member      = 'ACAA';
```

The generation string and its members have the following characteristics:

- Each member has the same number of characters as the others
- All members of the string are alpha sorted
- Each set of siblings will always be adjacent to one another
- Siblings are those members who share the exact same combination of letters except the last letter

Continuing the example...

```
// This is how I go about extracting the desired result: ACAA,ACAB,ACAD
var mParent     = member.substr(0, member.length - 1) ;
var mPattern    = mParent + '[A-Z]';
var mPattern    = '(.*)((' + mPattern + ')(,$1)*)(.*)'; // Trouble is here
var mRegex      = new RegExp(mPattern);
var mSiblings   = generation.replace(mRegex, '$2');
```

The trouble spot identified above concerns regex quantifiers in the constructed pattern. As it is above, everything is set to greedy, so the value of mSiblings is:

```
ACAD
```

That's only the last member. Changing mPattern to be less greedy in hopes of extracting the other members yields the following

```
// Reluctant first expression yields ACAA
var mPattern = '(.*?)((' + mPattern + ')(,$1)*)(.*)'; 

// Reluctant last expression yields ACAD,AEAB,AEAD,AFAA
var mPattern = '(.*)((' + mPattern + ')(,$1)*)(.*?)'; 

// Reluctant first and last yields ACAA,ACAB,ACAD,AEAB,AEAD,AFAA
var mPattern = '(.*?)((' + mPattern + ')(,$1)*)(.*?)';
```

If I could make the middle expression possessive, this would be problem solved. Something like this:

```
// Make as many "middle" matches as possible by changing (,$1)* to (,$1)*+
var mPattern = '(.*?)((' + mPattern + ')(,$1)*+)(.*?)';
```

But as I have read (and have the syntax errors to prove it), JavaScript doesn't support possessive regular expression quantifiers. Can someone suggest a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem is the `$1`.  Within a regex, you would refer to capturing group #1 using `\1`, not `$1`.  The `(,$1)*` in your regex is never going to match anything.  But a group reference isn't going to do any good anyway.

When you use a group reference in a regex, you aren't applying that part of the regex again, you're simply matching the same thing that it matched the first time.  That is, `(ACA[A-Z])(,\1)*` will match `ACAA,ACAA`, but not `ACAA,ACAB` or `ACAA,ACAC`.  If you want to do that, you need to repeat the actual regex: `(ACA[A-Z])(,ACA[A-Z])*`.  Since you're generating the regex dynamically, that shouldn't be a problem.

Note that that's the whole regex: `ACA[A-Z](,ACA[A-Z])*`.  There's no need to match the stuff preceding or following the part that interests you; that's just making the job more complicated (and the results more confusing).  You can access the match result directly, instead of using that "replace" gimmick:

```
var match = mRegex.exec(generation);
if (match != null) {
    mSiblings = match[0];
}
```

Comment: If the length of each of the member is not fixed, then word boundary is necessary. If it's fixed, then the current solution works.

Comment: @nhahtdh: What you say is true, but the OP did say all members would be the same length, and that siblings would be identical except for the last letter.  While the code fragments and the claimed outputs are confusing, the actual *question* (about the first third of the text) is clear on those points.